# JS touchstart event doesn't fire on Windws 8 tablet

Tags: javascript, windows-8, touch

I have an application that is meant only for desktop devices with mouse. I want to handle it nice for 2 in 1 devices, with touchscreen and mouse. So I decided to do it like that, whenever user touches screen, display a modal telling that the application doesn't work for touch events and prompt the user to click "ok" button using mouse to continue. This doesn't work however. Touch events on Windows 8 tablet seems to work just like mouse. The modal is not displayed. I'm using touchstart event to display it. Even jQuery resizable seems to be working with this touch. Why is that? How can I diffierntiate between mouse and touch? Why touchstart doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

Check out PointerEvents

> Starting with Windows 8, Internet Explorer supports W3C Pointer Events
>   for handling user input. Pointer events are modeled after traditional
>   mouse events, except they use the abstract concept of a pointer to
>   apply across all user input modalities, including mouse, touch, and
>   pen. Use pointer events to create a seamless user experience across
>   user input methods by writing to a single set of events that work
>   across hardware capabilities.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn433244(v=vs.85).aspx